# Unlink IDE and editor theme in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

While changing the editor theme, I accidentally clicked on this dialog:

[image: WebStorm theme dialog]

How do I get back to the previous behaviour where I can use a dark editor theme with light IDE theme?

Comment: Just change editor's color schema manually -- it should not touch the GUI Theme this way (it's only when you are changing GUI Theme it may change color schema as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the IDE theme back to dark by selecting any dark theme from `Appearance & Behavior` -> `Appearance` -> `Theme` in the Preferences dialog.

[image: picture of webstorm preferences showing Theme]

If you type "Theme" in the preferences search it should highlight it. The themes you have available will depend on which ones you have installed.

To change the code/editor theme, change the `Editor` -> `Colors & Fonts` -> `Scheme` (search for "Colors & Fonts")

[image: picture of webstorm preferences showing Colors & Fonts]